# Run multiple docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I would like to be able to launch multiple docker services when a client is connecting to my server and be able to manage multiple clients.

After receiving contents from this client, I am using `docker-compose up` to build and run the services using its contents via a `docker-compose.yml`. When another client was connecting using the same content, it was `re-creating` the dockers because they had the same `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`; so I changed this environment variable by the `id` of the client via the `.env`. My issue is now that, when the client is disconnecting, I would like to close only its concerning services. How can I specify a `docker-compose down` for "a specific `docker-compose up`"? Is it the good approach?

Here is the relative PR: https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/pull/4259/files

**EDIT**
To not close all my images but only the images concerned by the current docker-compose.yml, it added the flag `--rmi local` ; `docker-compose down --rmi local`

Comment: With docker-compose up (or down) your can name the service you want to start or stop in the options. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does not seems possible to name a specific service for down (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down). But anyway, I solved my issue by adding the flag `--rmi local`. I am editing my question as I am still wondering if it is a good general approach to launch multiple docker-compose up for multiple instances.

Comment: Oh i am sorry, have't went through your source. You're building each time from dockerfile. Sure then you're right in removing the images as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very broad question, so basically:
`docker-compose up and down` starts or stops exactly what is referenced in the corresponding docker-compose-file. If you want to take down a special "up" make sure the file just contains stuff from this special up. This is quite nasty for offering multi-tenancy in my opinion but depends hardly on the use-case. One problem is that doors are wide opened for DoS-Flood (e.g. unintentionally by many client connections or problems in stopping services).

To give a proper advice in an alternative it would be necessary to know what you want to achieve and what are your needs.
A better way e.g. (quite close to your approach) would be to use replicas (docker-compose v3) and spin them up and down by `docker-compose scale`. You can easily limit them in docker-compose file number- and resource-wise. Read about `deploy`-Feature in [Docker-Compose Deploy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy)